# How to prove that $ d(P,Q)=\sup_{\phi(X)\in [0,1]}|\int_R \phi(x)(p(x)-q(x))d\mu(x)| $?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $P$ and $Q$ be probability distributions with densities $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on the line. Define the distance between $P$ and $Q$ by
$$
d(P,Q):=\int_R |p(x)-q(x)|d\mu(x)
$$

I try to prove that
$$
d(P,Q)=2\sup_{\phi(X)\in [0,1]}|\int_R \phi(x)(p(x)-q(x))d\mu(x)|
$$
Moreover, we have
$$
\frac{1}{4}[d(P,Q)]^2\le 1-\left(\int_R \sqrt{p(x)q(x)}d\mu(x)\right)^2
$$

---

I am a little bit confused about how to deal with this function $\phi(x)$? I can show that

$$
2\sup_{\phi(X)\in [0,1]}|\int_R \phi(x)(p(x)-q(x))d\mu(x)|\le 2\sup_{\phi(X)\in [0,1]}|\int_R (p(x)-q(x))d\mu(x)|
$$

My idea is that to prove that
$$
d(P,Q)\ge 2\sup_{\phi(X)\in [0,1]}|\int_R \phi(x)(p(x)-q(x))d\mu(x)|
$$
and
$$
d(P,Q)\le 2\sup_{\phi(X)\in [0,1]}|\int_R \phi(x)(p(x)-q(x))d\mu(x)|
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly,
$$
\left|\int_R \phi(x)(p(x)-q(x))d\mu(x)\right|\le \int_R |p(x)-q(x)|d\mu(x)
$$
and so
$$
\sup_{\phi(X)\in [0,1]}\left|\int_R \phi(x)(p(x)-q(x))d\mu(x)\right|\le d(P,Q).
$$
For $\phi={\rm sgn}(p-q)$ the left-hand side is equal to $d(P,Q)$ and so
$$
\sup_{\phi(X)\in [0,1]}\left|\int_R \phi(x)(p(x)-q(x))d\mu(x)\right|= d(P,Q).
$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you please also take a look at the second inequality? I am not sure how to prove that.

Comment: Also, did you miss 2 in front of the $\sup$?

Comment: I didn't miss a $2$. This solves your question, if I have the time I will look at the other one, but that is already another question and so you should ask it separately.