# How to prove that $ \frac{1}{4}[d(P,Q)]^2\le 1-\left(\int_R \sqrt{p(x)q(x)}d\mu(x)\right)^2 $?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality

Following this question:[How to prove that $ d(P,Q)=\sup_{\phi(X)\in [0,1]}|\int_R \phi(x)(p(x)-q(x))d\mu(x)| $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731651/how-to-prove-that-frac14dp-q2-le-1-left-int-r-sqrtpxqxd-mux/4731659#4731659).

Let $P$ and $Q$ be probability distributions with densities $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on the line. Define the distance between $P$ and $Q$ by
$$
d(P,Q):=\int_R |p(x)-q(x)|d\mu(x)
$$

We have $$
d(P,Q)=\sup_{\phi(X)\in [0,1]}|\int_R \phi(x)(p(x)-q(x))d\mu(x)|
$$

But how to prove that
$$
\frac{1}{4}[d(P,Q)]^2\le 1-\left(\int_R \sqrt{p(x)q(x)}d\mu(x)\right)^2
$$

---

I have no idea about the proof. It seems that we need to use the Cauchy inequality. Do we have
$$
|p(x)-q(x)|^2\ge 2p(x)q(x)?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer/plug: lifted from Appendix B of my survey on distribution testing, available here: https://ccanonne.github.io/survey-topics-dt.html (Lemma B.1): this is, basically, the relation between total variation distance and Hellinger distance.*

$$\begin{align*}
\int_\mathbb{R} |p-q|d\mu &= \int_\mathbb{R} |\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}|\cdot |\sqrt{p}-\sqrt{q}|d\mu  \\
&\leq \sqrt{\int_\mathbb{R} (\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})^2d\mu}\sqrt{\int_\mathbb{R} (\sqrt{p}-\sqrt{q})^2d\mu} \tag{Cauchy–Schwarz}\\
&= \sqrt{2+ 2\int_\mathbb{R} \sqrt{pq}\,d\mu}\sqrt{2- 2\int_\mathbb{R} \sqrt{pq}\,d\mu}  \tag{$\star$}\\
&= 2\sqrt{1-\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sqrt{pq}\,d\mu\right)^2}
\end{align*}$$
where $(\star)$ follows from expanding the square and recalling that both $p,q$ integrate to one: $\int_\mathbb{R} p \, d\mu = \int_\mathbb{R} q \, d\mu = 1$.

So, squaring both sides and dividing by 4,
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{4}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} |p-q|d\mu\right)^2 &\leq 1-\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sqrt{pq}\,d\mu\right)^2
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to your work!

Comment: Do you miss square on the last line right hand side?

Comment: @Hermi I did, thanks for noticing (and adrien_vb for fixing) that typo.